# How should I order the sentence with "noun clause" and "wh clause"?

Tags: grammar, word-order, ambiguity, direct-objects, noun-clause

I hope that all of you have a nice day.

When the subject is a bit long, we can use "it" as the representative of the "that-noun clause".
What if the object or subject complement is also long?
For example;

> I consider that it's not normal that I'm always criticized even for my
> little mistakes that don't affect anyone.

This is my original sentence.
I'd like to add new information to it because there is one more situation.

> 1-) I consider that it's not normal where you are never criticized for
> your serious mistakes that I'm always criticized even for my little
> mistakes that don't affect anyone.
>
> 2-) I consider that it's not normal that I'm always criticized even
> for my little mistakes that don't affect anyone where you are never
> criticized for your serious mistakes.
>
> 3-) I consider that that I'm always criticized even for my little
> mistakes that don't affect anyone is not normal where you are never
> criticized for your serious mistakes.

Question 1: Which one is better, or all of them can be used?

Question 2: In the third version, there are **two** "that" as you can see, and one of them is for "*consider*", the other one is for the sentence "*I'm always...*".
Should I use both of them or remove one of them?

Thank you.